# How can I mathematiically enforce a set of constraints on a range from 0 to 1?

Tags: constraints

I have a function $f(x)$ which needs to be bounded between 2 functions $g(x)$ and $h(x)$.  Functions $g(x)$ and $h(x)$ are guaranteed never to intersect.

I have a function $f(x) = a + bx + cx^2$ and I need to select parameters $a$, $b$, and $c$ such that $\int_0^1 f(x) dx = w$ and $g(x) < f(x) < h(x)$ for $x \in [0,1]$.

How would I construct f(x) to enforce these constraints?  All functions here are polynomials.

Edit: I have a hypothesis of how I might solve this, but I don't know how to formalize it:

If I specify this as an optimization problem,
\begin{equation}
\min_{a,b,c} \left(\int_0^1 f(x) dx - w\right)^2
\end{equation}
and apply g(x) and h(x) as constraints to that optimization, perhaps such that I integrate $f(x) - h(x)$ only if the constraint is broken (and the same for $g(x)$) I could do something with Lagrange multipliers and slack variables... but I'm not sure how I would apply that.

Comment: Can you give the explicit formulas for $g$ and $h$? It is not solvable in general.

Comment: The function $g(x)$ is a parabola similar to $x^2$, the function $h(x)$ is a vertical line above $h(0) = 3$.  Perhaps my constraints are not well written, as the constraint is simply that f(x) does not intersect h(x) anywhere.

Answer (score 1):

When $g$ and $h$ form a narrow hose going up-down-up there will be no quadratic polynomial $f$ in between.

Comment: Yes, but not on the interval $x \in [0,1]$